# Get a sum of values inside a dictionary

Tags: python, list

I have a dictionary where key is a country name and value is a list of two or 1 numbers. I need to get the sum of those two values in a form of a dictionary where key is the country and the value is the sum.

I've tried using sum() but I get an error that states - can only concatenate list (not "int") to list.

```
country_home = sorted(Counter(data['home_team']).most_common()) # gives back ('America', 18)
country_away = sorted(Counter(data['away_team']).most_common()) # gives back ('America', 10)
```

```
        country_away = sorted(Counter(data['away_team']).most_common())
        d = defaultdict(list)
        for a, b in country_home + country_away:
            d[a].append(b)
        print(d) # gives back {'America': [18, 10], 'Canada': [37, 65], 'Mexico: [10], ...}
```

The expected result is a list or a dictionary

```
{'America': [28], 'Canada': [102], ... }
```

Comment: Can you share a sample of the input?

Comment: The imput is a CSV file where column A is country names and column B is country names as well. I need to add how many times country name was mentioned in A and B columns. Background - column A national football country names that played at home and column B national football country name that played away - goal is to count how many games each country have played in total.

Comment: Provide a full [mcve]

Comment: Well if you're loading it using pandas, just share a sample anyway. Please check how to provide a [minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You should be able to just add two `Counter` instances

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just do:

```
Counter(data['home_team'] + data['away_team']).most_common()
```

Example:

```
from collections import Counter, OrderedDict
data = {
    'home_team': 'America America  America  America America America Canada'.split(),
    'away_team': 'America America  America  America America America Canada'.split()
}

print(OrderedDict(Counter(data['home_team'] + data['away_team']).most_common()))
```

Output :

```
OrderedDict([('America', 12), ('Canada', 2)])
```

If you don't care about order use `dict(..)` instead of `OrderedDict(..)`

Or you can do this:

```
  print(dict((Counter(data['home_team'])+ Counter(data['away_team'])).most_common()))
```

Answer (score 1):

With minimal changes to your code, following should work.

```
     country_away = sorted(Counter(data['away_team']).most_common())
        d = defaultdict(list)
        for a, b in country_home + country_away:
            d[a].append(b)
            d[a] = [sum(d[a])] # sum up the list
        print(d) # should give back {'America': [28], 'Canada': [102], 'Mexico': [10]...}
```

Is this what you wanted to do?

Cheers

Comment: You are welcome! :) it would be great if you could also accept the answer in case you think it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Without harming the original dictionary you can try:

```
a = {'America':[18,20],'Canada':[37,65],'c':[4,5,6]}
b = {x:a[x] for x in a}
b = {x : [] for x in b}
for i in a:
    b[i].append(sum(a[i]))
print(b)
```

Output:

```
{'America': [38], 'Canada': [102], 'c': [15]}
```

This way whenever a new key is added to the first dictionary, it will be added to diciontary `b`.

Answer (score 0):

You can process the dictionary using dict comprehension

```py
d = {'America':[18,20],'Canada':[37,65],'c':[4,5,6]}
res = {k:[sum(v)] for k,v in d.items()}
print(res)
```

Output:

```
{'America': [38], 'Canada': [102], 'c': [15]}
```